# Is it possible to un-furl a non-url with a Slack app?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there a way via a Slack app to do an un-furl on a string that is matched, but isn't a URL? For example, maybe there a few birds names that if seen in a message should get highlighted and replaced with a link to the bird on Wikipedia.

`I saw a robin eating a worm` would become `I saw a [robyn](https://wikipedia.org/robyn) eating a worm`

Is that possible? I was able to match for `robin` in my app and then called `chat.update` with updated text, but it failed with `cant_update_message`. I think it might because my app is trying to update a message written by a user. Or maybe I setup the scopes wrong and need to fix it.